# Given 2x2 rank-1 matrix A = xy^T where the dot product of x and y = 3

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, matrix-rank

Consider a 2 ×2 rank-1 matrix A= ⃗u⃗vT . Suppose you somehow know that ⃗u ·⃗v = 3; find the
eigenvalues, the determinant and the trace of A.

I am confused about how I am supposed to find the elements of A given only the dot product of two vectors that form A when multiplied together.

Comment: Try putting $u = (a, b)^\top$ and $v = (c, d)^\top$. What would be the trace and determinant of $A$ in terms of $a, b, c, d$? You might be able to work out the determinant purely based on the rank! Write out the value of the dot product too, in terms of $a, b, c, d$. Once you have the trace and determinant, it should be easy to work out the eigenvalues (given the multiply to give the determinant, and sum to give the trace).

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

- An invertible $2\times 2$ matrix has rank $2$. What does this tell you about the determinant of a rank $1$ matrix?
- What is the relationship between the determinant of a matrix and its eigenvalues? From the determinant alone, you can deduce one of the eigenvalues.
- Write the trace of $A$ in terms of the entries of $x$ and $y$, noting that
  $$
  A = xy^T = \pmatrix{x_1y_1 & x_1y_2\\x_2y_1&x_2y_2}.
  $$
  How does this result relate to the dot-product of $x$ and $y$?
- What is the relationship between the trace of a matrix and its eigenvalues? Using the trace and the eigenvalue that you found in the previous step, find the other eigenvalue.